# Enhanced List Type for Dynamic Related List- Single component

Tags: salesforce-lightning, dynamic-related-list

I have added a Dynamic Related List - Single to my record page in Lightning App builder but I see that when I change from Related List - Single to Dynamic Related List - Single the Related List Type option for 'Enhanced List' is no longer available. I need to add a custom Quick Action in Lightning Experience alongside the Standard Buttons and it says that they can only be seen when the Enhanced List Type is selected. Does anyone know how I can go around this? I need to retain the Dynamic Related List since I need to be able to add more than one Related List Field in my component